# Golang to create a main layout webpage

Tags: html, go, render

I'm new to Golang and am trying to start a web server using Go. I already wrote the html, css and js for the basic layout but am having trouble displaying the website after starting the server.

Using this page as a guide [link](http://sanatgersappa.blogspot.com/2013/11/creating-master-page-for-your-go-web-app.html). Just using my own written html, CSS and JS files as visual layout.

What happens is the header, footer, etc combines just fine but it is displayed as text in the browser, with tags and all. I'm not sure why it is not being displayed properly. I am not sure if it could be because I'm not rendering as html using templates.HTML but I cannot find much information on this. Thank you all in advance! Go code as below: [Github link](https://github.com/jzng89/TLDR-GO)

```
 package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

type Page struct {
    Title string
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//Compile templates on start
var templ = func() *template.Template {
    t := template.New("")
    err := filepath.Walk("./", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if strings.Contains(path, ".html") {
            fmt.Println(path)
            _, err = t.ParseFiles(path)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }
        return err
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return t
}()

//---------------------------------------Page Handlers----------------------------------//
//Handler for homepage
func homepageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Home")
    err := templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", &Page{Title: "Welcome to TL;DR"})
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

//Handler for about page
func aboutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("About")
    err := templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about", &Page{Title: "About TL;DR"})
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

//Handler for test Page
func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        fmt.Println("Test")
        testT, _ := template.ParseFiles("static/test.html")
        testT.Execute(w, nil)
    }
}

func main() {
    //--------------------------------------Routers-------------------------------------//
    http.HandleFunc("/", homepageHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/about", aboutHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/test", testHandler)

    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    //log to file
    f, err := os.OpenFile("serverlog.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error opening file: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    logger := log.New(f, "Logged : ", log.LstdFlags)
    log.SetOutput(f)

    //start server
    logger.Println("Starting server on port 9090")
    logger.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil))

}
```

**Edit:** Updated 20181214

[File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa63e.png)

[Snapshot of webpage after code update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXt9T.png)

My html code is basically the same format as the website but I do have some javascript and local css files which are part of my html (only for simple transition, no jquery). Could this affect the parsing? Go version `go version go1.10.1 windows/amd64`

**Solved:** Updated 20181215

Thanks @A.R pointing out the issue with my html header having extra characters!

Comment: `w.Header.Add("Content-Type", "text/html")` before executing the template.

Comment: I get `w.Header.Add undefined (type func() http.Header has no field or method Add)` . Is it a go version issue or am I not including a library needed?

Comment: @JianZhenNg: you're welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (works for me):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func homepageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Home")
    templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main", &Page{Title: "Welcome to TL;DR"})
}
func aboutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("About")
    templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about", &Page{Title: "About TL;DR"})
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homepageHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/about", aboutHandler)
    fmt.Println("Server started on port 8080")
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

var templ = func() *template.Template {
    t := template.New("")
    err := filepath.Walk("./", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if strings.Contains(path, ".html") {
            fmt.Println(path)
            _, err = t.ParseFiles(path)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }
        return err
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return t
}()

type Page struct {
    Title string
}
```

---

`main.html` file content:

```
{{define "main"}}
{{template "header" .}}
<div class="content">
    <h2>Main</h2>
    <div>This is the Main page</div>
</div>
{{template "footer" .}}
{{end}}
```

---

`about.html` file content:

```
{{define "about"}}
{{template "header" .}}
<div class="content">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <div>This is the About page</div>
</div>
{{template "footer" .}}
{{end}}
```

---

`footer.html` file content:

```
{{define "footer"}}
<p class="navbar-text navbar-fixed-bottom">Go Rocks!</p>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
{{end}}
```

---

`header.html` file content:

```
{{define "header"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>{{.Title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-bottom: 70px;
        }

        .content {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Go App</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    {{end}}
```

---

Notes:
And see [this](https://gowebexamples.com/templates/) for templates.

Edit:
in your `static/template/header.html` file in line 2 remove extra `</`  before `<!DOCTYPE html>` (inside red circle in this image):
[image]

Comment: thank you for the assist, after modifying my code to match yours I found that my templates were not being parsed. I changed it to what you provided and now the templates are parsed but I still get the same problem, page displays text instead of the html.

Comment: updated as requested. Do you need me to include my html codes for header/footer etc? As stated in my updated I do have some javascripts (separated file), not sure if that could affect the parsing.

Comment: @JianZhenNg: go to your file: `https://github.com/jzng89/TLDR-GO/blob/master/static/template/header.html` and inside this file at line 2 before `<!DOCTYPE html>` you have extra characters: `</`  just delete these `</` extra chars and you are good to Go!

Comment: oh wow @A.R, thank you for pointing it out! First time writing html since primary school did not notice this could cause parsing issues. Now I gotta find out how to get the CSS to work too. I'll work it out first on my own so thanks again!

Comment: I learned so much here after failing to find a good example in multiple golang books.

Answer (score -1):

You are not following the tutorial exactly as it seems.

You are missing a "**.Title**" property which is required in the "**header**" template, it is failing here.

(if you open you developer tools will see that the index or about pages are broken and not parsed correctly)

Please add Page struct in your code

```
//A Page structure
type Page struct {
    Title string
}
```

It is used in the handler functions

```
//Handler for homepage
func homepageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    display(w, "main", &Page{Title: "Home"})
}
```

And it is called in the display function

```
func display(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, data interface{}) {
    templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl, data)
}
```

One more thing in your Homepage handler you are calling ExecuteTemplate with "index"

```
//Handler for homepage
func homepageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", "Welcome to TL;DR")
}
```

This should match with the "**main.html**" template as

```
{{define "index"}}
```

Comment: I have added the Page struct and still get the same issue. It still only displays the page as pure text. I don't think there is an issue with my html code because when I copied out the text displayed and save it as a separate html and open it it works normally.

Comment: I have checked my implementation yesterday and it works as expected. Can you put your code in github repo, I cannot help otherwise :)

Comment: </<!DOCTYPE html> @A.R for rescue :) Cheers